# Error in Shell Scripting

Tags: shell

When I am running this script to update a table in MySQL, it throws this error:

```
facilitycreation.sh: line 3: echo_________________: command not found
facilitycreation.sh: line 8: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
facilitycreation.sh: line 10: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Can someone tell me what is the error here?

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Facility Creation"
echo"_________________"
while read address_line1 address_line2 city state country postal_code
do
echo`mysql -u**** -h********* facilities -e "insert into addresses ($'address_line1',$'address_line2',$'city',$'state',$'country',$'postal_code',now(),now());"`

slepp 10

echo 'mysql -u**** -h****** facilities -e "Select * form addresses where city =$'city';`
done < details.txt
```

and `details.txt` file has details in this format:

```
add1
add2
cityname
Statename
Pincode
India
```

Comment: This is unreadable, get the formatting right, otherwise we won't be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

A space is missing between your call to echo and the string:

```
echo"_________________"
```

will be interpreted by bash as

```
echo_________________
```

As a side note, the double quotes are not necessary here